# Why i need to define bean javaMailSenderImpl in config file,when i am using external property file in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to use external property file in spring Boot application.But when i am running the application it is suggesting me to define bean of javaMailSender.

When i am defining a bean of javaMailSenderImpl it is running fine.
But while sending any email it is showing exception

Failed messages: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;

Here is my code-

```
@Bean
public org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSenderImpl(){
    return new org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl();
}
@Bean
public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    properties.setLocation(new FileSystemResource("C:\\Users\\Rishabh Sharma\\Desktop\\app.properties"));
    properties.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(false);
    return properties;
}
```

Comment: Remove both beans, and transfer the content of `app.properties` to `application.properties` and use the proper `spring.mail` settings to configure the `JavaMailSender`.

Comment: when i am putting all the properties in application.properties it is working fine.But i want to define all my properties in external property file.

Comment: Still put them in an ex eternal properties file next to the jar. Spring Boot will load that as well. I strongly suggest a read of the [Externalize Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config) section of the reference guide.

Comment: i want to put the file in my directory apart from project directory for that i am loading the file from custom location then why it is not loading mail properties from this file @M.Deinum

Comment: Again I suggest a read of the section I pointed you to. Hint don't load the file yourself.

Comment: okay i am looking in to it thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Actually what worked for me is to use @propertysource() annotation. it is working fine in war too.